# PrimeNG's calendar event for 'onClose' not firing when tabbing out of a field?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am currently using PrimeNG's calendar component, and I am depending on the calendar's `onClose` to update my underlying data when a user types in a date. However, I have noticed that when the focus leaves the calendar via pressing the tab button, the `onClose` event does not fire.

The template is something simple, like:

```
<p-calendar
  ...
  (onClose)="closeEvent($event)">
</p-calendar>
```

And the function, for testing purposes, just log a message:

```
closeEvent(ev) {
  console.log('close event fired');
}
```

The message is properly logged to screen when the user exits the calendar by clicking away from it, but not doesn't fire when tabbing away.

However, validation does seem to fire when tabbing out; If I input an invalid date before tabbing out, it goes back to the default date.

Is this a bug? I could't find anything similar in the [issues list in PrimeNG's repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues).

I tried using the `onBlur` event, but that causes an issue where the calendar popup does not close when a value is selected the first time, and the event is fired with the previous calendar value. A date in the calendar needs to be selected a second time for the model to actually update, and the `onBlur` event to be called with the correct value.

The above code was tested in Chrome and Firefox.

We are using PrimeNG version 6.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is working code

app.component.html

```
<div> 
  <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" (onClose)="hello()" [showIcon]="true" [showOnFocus]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prime-ex';
  date1 = new Date();;

  hello(){
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CalendarModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the output in browser is as shown below. Yes it is triggering the event.
Please either post full code or debug it. There is no bug. I did not install font-awesome so icons are not appearing properly. This code works perfectly with tab-out too.

[image]

Comment: That seems like it didn't work - that event never fires.

Comment: with close too not onClose ?

Comment: `close` never fired for me. `onClose` didn't fire with tabbing out

Comment: But unless you post the entire code no one can help you out . You may try with the code posted, It is working fine and may be match

Comment: Yeah, I can see the code posted works. I tried it on stackblitz as well and it worked without issue. This makes my problem more confusing.I also cannot share the entire code as I am not sure what I am allowed to share. I'll update the question with more information.